# Can preset name be used in QGIS expression?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Does anyone know if it is possible to use a Preset name in the expression builder in the Print Layout?

I was hoping to use the present name as the Map Title in a text box, but can't find a variable in the expression builder that might be able to call it in.

Comment: You could build you own expression function. The project instance will return the visibilityPresetCollection: QgsProject.instance().visibilityPresetCollection().presets(). Not sure how to get the selected one. Also be aware that you may have to get the presets from the print composer instead, since you also can change preset here.